# what is the carry-out from the shifter of ARM CPU

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-shift, carryflag, status-register

I'm reading 'ARM Architecture Reference Manual' to write a Game Boy Advance emulator which has an ARM7TDMI CPU. I'm not familiar with ARM architecture. The manual mentions 'the carry-out from the shifter'.

> The < shifter_operand > value is formed by rotating (to the right) an 8-bit immediate value to any even bit
>   position in a 32-bit word. If the rotate immediate is zero, the carry-out from the shifter is the value of the C
>   flag, otherwise, it is set to bit[31] of the value of  < shifter_operand > .

What is that? What is it used for? Do I need to implement it? Are there any relations between the C flag of CPSR and 'the carry-out from the shifter'?

Comment: You're writing an emulator for a CPU you're not familiar with?  Why?  You know QEMU exists, right?  It would also help to narrow down the architecture you're trying to simulate, because not all ARM cores are the same.  ARMv6, v7?

Comment: This feature goes way back so I cant see how armv6/armv7 would change it without trashing the instruction set.   Should also be in the documentation.  Note the ARM ARM which got split later, started with armv4 the white book the blue book the thick white book which was then released digitally then armv6 was sorta glued into that, then armv7 came out in its own book (arm arm forked at that point) and armv6 spans across both, so armv6 should be covered in what they call the armv5 which is armv4,5,6.  will check arm7

Comment: dont have my print books handy the white, blue and thick white to confirm they say the same thing, I would be surprised if they didnt.

Comment: A logical instruction with the rotation field set to 0b0000 does not affect APSR.C. Otherwise, a logical flag-setting
instruction sets APSR.C to the value of bit[31] of the modified immediate constant.

Comment: from the armv7-ar arm arm.  so all of them from armv4 to armv7 work the same way.  armv8 is a completely incompatible format, and before armv4 is acorn, different documentation.

Comment: Yes, if you are making an instruction set simulator then you need to simulate the instruction set.

Comment: and you will see this pattern continues for other shifted operands if shift is this then that else if shift is this then that...No reason not to implement these then have to fix them later.

Comment: @cooperised I'm interested in emulating Game Boy Advance which has 
an ARM7TDMI CPU, so I also need to emulate the ARM CPU.

Comment: Nice project, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other quotes from the ARM ARM some near your quote.

> As well as producing the shifter operand, the shifter produces a
>   carry-out which some instructions write into the Carry Flag.

...

> Data-processing operands - Immediate

and a diagram that shows 27:25 = 0b001, 11:8 is rotate_imm and 7:0 is immed_8

> The shifter_operand value is formed by rotating (to the right) an
>   8-bit immediate value to any even bit position in a 32-bit word. If
>   the rotate immediate is zero, the carry-out from the shifter is the
>   value of the C flag, otherwise, it is set to bit[31] of the value of
>   .

Think about what instructions would want to rotate but are not driving the Carry flag, ADD is not one of them for example

> C Flag = CarryFrom(Rn + shifter_operand)

But MOV would be a prime candidate

> C Flag = shifter_carry_out

So if the rotate_imm is zero which means the immediate is between 0x00000000 and 0x000000FF right?  Then shifter_carry_out is the C flag, basically the C flag doesnt change or get updated.  But if the rotate_imm is non-zero then the shifter_carry_out comes from bit 31 of the resulting shift which for the MOV instruction (and perhaps some others)(with the S bit set) becomes the new C flag.

Not vague at all, quite clearly documented.

Note there are many documented and undocumented gems like this that are used to see if a clone is indeed a clone and/or is stolen IP.  There werent that many clones that made it AFAIK.  google picoturbo And to make it you needed to be an accurate clone and get all of these instructions right including the UNPREDICTABLE RESULTS ones of which some were predictable.

ARM released the Armulator source code years ago, basically the code that made ARM, the logic had to match armulator.  And we can take and use that and one would assume are legally free to do so based on the license.  QEMU has an instruction set simulator out there and there are some others, so while dancing around legal language to make a simulator and possibly publish it in some form (some ARM docs specifically call this out), they so far have allowed those to exist.  But certainly dont try to turn this into a clone in logic for yourself or to sell/publish.

So you can try this against hardware but you are further dancing on the fringes of legality.  Dont think you need to as your quote is covered within that same document.

Comment: Where can I download the Armulator source code? Is [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/armulator/)  released by ARM?

Comment: it is part of gdb.  that one you linked on initial inspection appears to have just stolen the name.  that doesnt look like arm's code it would have legalease on it.

Comment: yep, gdb sources sim/arm directory.

Comment: since it is a trademarked name looks like a number of people are breaking the law using it for their own simulators.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any specific architecture information, and of information about exactly which of the shift operations you wish to emulate, I can only give a vague answer.  But in general the carry out bit holds the value of the last bit to have been shifted 'out' of the register, whether or not that resulted in the bit being 'lost'.

The relationship between the shifter's carry out and the carry flag (as stored in the PSR) is that in common with almost all other data processing instructions, the carry flag is only updated if the `S` suffix is present in the instruction mnemonic.

So assuming flags are being set, for arithmetic and logical shifts (e.g. `ASL`, `LSL`), the carry flag tells you the value of the most recently 'lost' bit.  For rotate-without-carry operations (e.g. `ROR`), the carry flag mirrors the MSB (for shift-right) or the LSB (for shift-left) after the rotation.  For rotate-with-carry (e.g. `RRX`), the carry flag us used as a 33rd bit.

See [this page of the armasm user guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1361289852998.html) and its rather helpful diagrams.